# The url of the image without http is returned

Tags: django, image, url, django-rest-framework

I am writing a rest api application in the django rest framework in which I can post images.

I want to receive the url of the image: `https://path/image_name.jpg`

Here is my serializer class:

```
class Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
url = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_image_url')
...
def get_image_url(self, obj):
    return obj.image.url
```

In this case /media/filename.jpg is returned

If I add the https prefix, the link will be displayed, but if I click on it I get an error: browser can not connect to the server localhost

Comment: What is the final url?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you can definitely use `request.get_raw_uri()` to get the hostname with its protocol.
Trying something like
`image_url request.get_raw_uri() + url` , This will generate proper url of the image.

Comment: Are you suggesting the use of return HttpRequest().get_raw_uri() + obj.photo.url?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `serializers.ImageField` which will do all the conversions.

```
class Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.ImageField(source='image')
```

Alternatively, you can just add `'image'` to your `Serializer.Meta.fields` since that is a `ModelSerializer` and will generate everything for you (although the key would be `image` instead of `url`, but that shouldn't be an issue).